# Text to image in nice way - with automatic break of long lines and good font

Tags: php, gd

I am converting text into image so that users can directly share quotes into Facebook and Twitter.
I want to make the images with php gd. I have this code which works fine but it has some issues like long lines that are not breaking automatically. Also the font is not working as I want to use cosmic font.

Here is my code

```
  <?php
     header("Content-type: image/png");


      $string = ' <p>I think the whole under-eye-bag thing is hereditary, and I just got lucky.</p> <p class="bq_fq_a"> <a id="qut" title="julianna_margulies"> Julianna Margulies </a> </p> <br>';

  $font  = '12';
       $fonttype = '/path/cosmic.TTF';

   $width  = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string);
    $height = imagefontheight($font);

   $image = imagecreatetruecolor ($width,$height);
    $white = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
   $black = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
    imagefill($image,0,0,$white);

  imagestring ($image,$font,0,0,$string,$black);

    imagepng ($image);
   imagedestroy($image);

      ?>
```

Comment: How about http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @AmalMurali i am converting text to image and text is coming from mysql

Comment: Hi, you may get this by imagemagic, look at here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label_lines

Comment: @jothikannan in existing script can i make those changes to look like big images